# In Rails 4, how do I reference an enum value when initializing my model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, enums, activemodel

I’m using Rails 4.2.  It is not an option to upgrade at this time.  I have this model

```
class OrderItem < ApplicationRecord
    …
  enum type: { data: “Data”, product: “Product” }
```

How do I initialize my object by referencing my enum?  I tried this

```
@order_item = OrderItem.new(
  order_item_params.merge(
    type: :product
  )
)
…
@order_item.save
```

But this results in the error

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `safe_constantize' for :product:Symbol
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TLDR:

```
class OrderItem < ApplicationRecord
  self.inheritance_column = 'definitely_not_type'
  enum type: { data: "Data", product: "Product" }
```

`type` is the default for the inheritance_column in Rails. This column is mainly used for Single Table Inheritance. When it is present ActiveRecord will use the values in this column as the class for each row it fetches from the database.

So given the table `animals` with these values:

```
id | type   | name
------------------------
1  | Cat    | Mr Mittens
2  | Dog    | Laika
3  | Snake  | Snek
```

When you call `Animal.all.map {|m| m.class}`  you will get [`Cat, Dog, Snake]`. Or at least you will if those contants actually exist.

If you're not actually using STI and want to use the name `type` you can just assign whatever you want to `self.inheritance_column`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess that you're running into an STI conflict, not an `enum` issue. Rails reserves the `type` column name for Single Table Inheritance (STI) and uses `type` to store the class name but you're trying to store a Symbol in `type`. ActiveRecord tries to convert the `type` value to a class, hence the complaint about not being able to call `safe_constantize` on your `:product` Symbol.

You could use a different name for your column or tell ActiveRecord to use a different name (presumably something you'd never use) for STI:

```
class OrderItem < ApplicationRecord
  self.inheritance_column = '_type'
  ...
end
```

I think `self.inheritance_column = nil` will also work in Rails4, I know `nil` works in Rails6 but I'm not certain about Rails4.

Comment: Wow I didn't know you could just assign nil.

Comment: @max Not certain if that works in Rails4 but I've been dragging around an `STISuppression` concern since Rails5 that uses `nil` to explicitly tell STI to go away.